# How to identify all country names mentioned in a string and split accordingly?

Tags: r, maps, stringr

I have a string that contains country and other region names. I am only interested in the country names and would ideally like to add several columns, each of which contains a country name listed in the string. Here is an exemplary code for the way the dataframe lis set up:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3),
                 country = c("Cote d'Ivoire Africa Developing Economies West Africa",
                              "South Africa United Kingdom Africa BRICS Countries",
                             "Myanmar Gambia Bangladesh Netherlands Africa Asia"))
```

If I only split the string by space, those countries which contain a space get lost (e.g. "United Kingdom"). See here:

```
df2 <- separate(df, country, paste0("C",3:8), sep=" ")
```

Therefore, I tried to look up country names using the world.cities dataset. However, this only seems to loop through the string until there is non-country name. See here:

```
library(maps)
library(stringr)
all_countries <- str_c(unique(world.cities$country.etc), collapse = "|")
df$c1 <- sapply(str_extract_all(df$country, all_countries), toString)
```

I am wondering whether it's possible to use the space a delimiter but define exceptions (like "United Kingdom"). This might obviously require some manual work, but appears to be most feasible solution to me. Does anyone know how to define such exceptions? I am of course also open to and thankful for any other solutions.

**UPDATE:**

I figured out another solution using the countrycode package:

```
library(countrycode)
countries <- data.frame(countryname_dict)
countries$continent <- countrycode(sourcevar = countries[["country.name.en"]],
                                   origin = "country.name.en",
                                   destination = "continent")

africa <- countries[ which(countries$continent=='Africa'), ]

library(stringr)
pat <- paste0("\\b", paste(africa$country.name.en , collapse="\\b|\\b"), "\\b")
df$country_list <- str_extract_all(df$country, regex(pat, ignore_case = TRUE))
```

Comment: It is possible, but you may multiple countries like that

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the quick reply. Could you specify how this would be possible? Thanks!

Comment: Depends on if you have a list of country names with multiple words

Comment: It looks like in the example in the beginning of my question; e.g. "South Africa United Kingdom Africa BRICS Countries"

Comment: What about `Cote d'Ivoire` ?  Is it a country

Comment: @akrun yes, `Cote d'Ivoire` is a country in Africa. West Africa to be precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
library(stringi)
vec <- stri_trans_general(countrycode::codelist$country.name.en, id = "Latin-ASCII")
stri_extract_all(df$country,regex = sprintf(r"(\b(%s)\b)",stri_c(vec,collapse = "|")))
[[1]]
[1] "Cote d'Ivoire"

[[2]]
[1] "South Africa"   "United Kingdom"

[[3]]
[1] "Gambia"      "Bangladesh"  "Netherlands"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works well. One minor note. There is an "=" missing. It has to be: `stri_extract_all(df$country,regex = sprintf(r="(\b(%s)\b)",stri_c(vec,collapse = "|")))`

Comment: I just discovered one problem in your solution which I have not managed to fix. There is both Nigeria and Niger in the text strings and all the Nigeria strings end up as Niger (looks like the first possible match is extracted). Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: @Lisa, you added an extra `=` YOU SHOULD DO EXACTLY AS POSTED ABOVE. there is no missing `=`. Take note of that

Comment: Thx for your reply @Onyambu, if I do so, I get the following error message in R: Error: unexpected string constant in "stri_extract_all(df$country,regex = sprintf(r"(\b(%s)\b)"".Meanwhile I found a solution using the countrycode package (see updated question)

Comment: @Lisa, it seems you are using an older version of R. Change it to `sprintf('\\b(%s)\\b',.......)` instead. The dotts mean maintain every other thing

Comment: Thanks you very much!